# Searching div for value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with multiple list items with divs having information stored, like this:

```
<li class="item ">
  <div class="name t-overflow">Symbiotic Ltd.</div>
  <div class="price">
    <span class="wai t-wai-reset">Stock Price: </span>$501.83
  </div>
</li>
<li class="item ">
  <div class="name t-overflow">Health Service</div>
  <div class="price">
    <span class="wai t-wai-reset">Stock Price: </span>$501.08
  </div>
</li>
```

What I need to do is check if a stock price is lower than X. So, for example. I need to combine Health Service and Stock Price as such: Health Service Stock Price: $501.08

so that I can then regex Health Service to find the Price of that. There are about 30 divs with this information for different stocks using the same div names. (name and price, for each one.)

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: put the price inside of a span with a class identifier, then accesing it by jquery

Comment: `var x = 1e3; 
$('li.item').each(function(i) { 
var price = parseFloat($(this).find('.price').text().replace(/[^.0-9]/g, '')); 
if (price < x) $(this).css('background', 'yellow' ); 
}); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each item is contained in a li(list item) the code below will loop through each li and place div text into an array that you can perform your regex on.

```html
Run Snippet below...
```

```js
CompanyPrices = [];

$('li.item').each(function() {
  CompanyPrices.push($(this).find('.name').text()+ " " +$(this).find('.price').text());
});

//logs final array to console..
console.log(CompanyPrices)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="item">
  <div class="name t-overflow">Symbiotic Ltd.</div>
  <div class="price">
    <span class="wai t-wai-reset">Stock Price: </span> $501.83 </div>
</li>
<li class="item">
  <div class="name t-overflow">Health Service</div>
  <div class="price">
    <span class="wai t-wai-reset">Stock Price: </span> $501.08 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the list items using **[each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** method and look for the **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** using **[find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** method, and then just **[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** the text using the `$` sign to get the price, and then you can just use the `if` statement to check if the price is smaller or bigger than any number you want:

```js
$('.item').each(function(){
  var price = $(this).find('.price').text().split('$')[1];
  console.log(price);
  if(price < 502){
    $(this).css('background', '#f00');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="item ">
  <div class="name t-overflow">Health Service</div>
  <div class="price">
    <span class="wai t-wai-reset">Stock Price: </span>
    $501.08
  </div>
</li>
<li class="item ">
  <div class="name t-overflow">Health Service</div>
  <div class="price">
    <span class="wai t-wai-reset">Stock Price: </span>
    $502.08
  </div>
</li>
<li class="item ">
  <div class="name t-overflow">Health Service</div>
  <div class="price">
    <span class="wai t-wai-reset">Stock Price: </span>
    $503.08
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are dynamic (ie from PHP), then you can store them in a variable. If they are set values (ie only change when you change the code), then you can try this solution:

```js
var stock1=document.getElementById('stock').innerHTML;
stock1=stock1.replace(/Stock price: \$([\d,.]*)/g,"$1");
document.getElementById('stock').innerHTML=stock1;
```

```html
<div id="stock">Stock price: $923.50</div>
<div id="otherstock">Stock price: $291,402.29</div>
```